# Navigation Editor in Android Studio says "no XML resource"

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

"nasd" is the main activity, and "nai" and "nash" are the two I have tried to get to activate from buttons on "nasd". On the phone, when a button is pressed the screen is blank white except the action bar. As far as I can tell, the app itself doesn't run into any errors, so there is probably something wrong with the way I start the activity.

activity_nasd.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#d4a017"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:longClickable="true">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="North Allegheny Intermediate High"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="North Allegheny Senior High"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Select a school:"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@mipmap/building"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

NASD.java

```
package com.example.james.northalleghenyschooldistrict;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;



    public class NASD extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nasd);
    findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(NASD.this, NASH.class));
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new
View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(NASD.this, NAI.class));
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        setTitle("NASD");
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_nasd, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_nai.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context="com.example.james.northalleghenyschooldistrict.NAI">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
        android:background="#000000"></WebView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:src="@mipmap/nai"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

NAI.java - has a few unused import statements, I was trying to add a webview but it kept crashing so I deleted it.

```
package com.example.james.northalleghenyschooldistrict;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;


public class NAI extends ActionBarActivity {

    public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState );
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nai);
    }
}
```

activity_nash.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:background="#000000"></WebView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@mipmap/nash"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

NASH.java

```
package com.example.james.northalleghenyschooldistrict;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;


public class NASH extends ActionBarActivity {

    public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState );
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nash);

    }
}
```

android_manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.james.northalleghenyschooldistrict" >

    <uses-permisson android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/school"
        android:label="NASD"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".NASD"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NAI"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_nai" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NASH"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_nash" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: where does it say no xml resource?

Comment: @ataulm In the navigation editor, sorry I forgot to say in the post. http://tools.android.com/navigation-editor

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu No, I havent seen any.

Comment: Okay.It's had to say what's wrong with your code.I created a test app and it works fine

Comment: -Check build.gradle files for errors or warnings
-Restart Android Studio
-Check for stable version updates
-Open SDK manager and get make sure all new packages and updates are installed
-(sometimes) Rebuilt the project
-Sync gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

["no xml resource"](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/95fe36019d65080014d2938314e689acead5b7fc/android/src/com/android/tools/idea/editors/navigation/AndroidRootComponent.java) is displayed in the [Navigation Editor](http://tools.android.com/navigation-editor) when the layout file that your Activity uses cannot be found.

Note that the Navigation editor is in development:

> Navigation Editor is being developed in the open so we can incorporate feedback into its feature set and design throughout the development process. If you'd like to use a tool like this in Android Studio, please send us your feedback.

I can replicate your situation by intentionally mis-spelling the layout resource for one of my activities:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.actisfsfvdity_seasons);
    ...
```

Then opening the Navigation Editor:

[image: no xml resource]

The process doesn't seem perfect. I have two modules in my project - `core` and `mobile` where all of my UI code is in mobile. By default, Navigation Editor tries to create a map of `core` and [it says "Invalid file name"](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2yrf6a/storyboard_like_tool_for_android_dev/cpccyw6). I can copy the `main.nvg.xml` file to the correct directory and then reopen the Navigation Editor and it'll work:

[image: copied main.nvg.xml file]

If your app runs properly, your layout files should be cool - I'd suggest deleting the `.navigation` directory and reopening the Navigation Editor; it'll regenerate the file but the images won't be spaced out as you had them before - you'll have to reshuffle them.

Answer (score 0):

To change the content of your activity, you should opt for fragments. When you click the button swap the new layout.xml

For reference:

[changing frangments dynamically](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/12/dynamic-change-fragment-using-java-code.htmlhttp://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/12/dynamic-change-fragment-using-java-code.html?m=1)

Comment: Yes, I think that is what I will do for this one, but it still doesnt explain why it comes up blank....

Comment: The reason MAY be that the webview element height occupies the parent views full height, since the bg color of web view is white it's showing up a blank  white. @JamesFenn

Comment: I will look at that. I have made a copy and attempted to use fragments instead of new activities and so far it's working ok.

Comment: Is there anything special you need to do to load a url into a webview in a fragment? Its saying "ERR_CACHE_MISS". The url loads fine in chrome.

Comment: Ok, everything has been fixed. The error from my most recent comment turned out to be a typo in "android.permission.INTERNET". I only used one s...

Comment: and no, it wasnt the webview taking up all the space, because I went back and changed the color a few times and nothing happened. I think it may have just been a weird glitch in android studio.

Comment: @JamesFenn wut, why is this marked as the answer to your original question..? "You should opt for fragments" why - there's no detail in the question that would suggest this is a good or a bad idea.

Comment: @ataulm well I tried using fragments and it worked, so obviously that was the solution to my problem :)

Comment: yes but that's different from being an answer to your question, which is an important distinction on a Q&A reference site like StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the mipmaps(nash and nai) really exist?

Change a background color to check if views exist.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Yes, the mipmaps exist. And changing the background color works for the first one but the second two stay blank white.